# Random Ints: Cannot be applied to given types

Tags: java, random

I am new to my intro to Java course and I am struggling with a program.  The program is supposed to simulate a race between a tortoise and a Hare.  Each has a variety of moves (ways to move on the race board) based on numbers that are generated randomly.  I am having a problem with the generation of the random numbers.  Below is my error message.  Can anyone help me fix the error message problem? Also if you see anything else in my code that needs fixing or anything at all, the help would be much appreciated.  Thanks, here's the code with the error message below.  P.S. I use blue J to write and compile my codes:

```
import java.util.Random;

class Race
{
    int [] race = new int[70];
    int tortoise;
    int hare;
    Random randomGenerator = new Random();
    public boolean again = true;
    public void StartRace()
    {
        tortoise = 1;
        hare = 1;
        System.out.println("AND THEY'RE OFF!!!!");
        while (tortoise < 70 && hare < 70)
        {
            MoveHare();
            MoveTortoise();
            DisplayCurrentLocation();
            String request;
        } //end while
        if 
            (tortoise > hare)
        {
            System.out.println("\n TORTOISE WINS!!");
        }
        else if
            (hare > tortoise)
        {   
            System.out.println("\n HARE WINS!!!");
        }
        else if
            (hare == tortoise)
        {
            System.out.println("TIE!!!");
        }
    }

    public void MoveTortoise()
    {
        int n = randomGenerator.next(1, 10);
        //fast plod
        if ( n <= 5)
            tortoise += 3;
        //slip
        else if (n == 9 || n == 10)
            tortoise -= 6;
        //slow plod
        else if (n == 6 || n == 7 || n == 8)
            ++tortoise;
            // protect from going past start
        if (tortoise < 1)
            tortoise = 1;
       // to make sure game ends
        else if (tortoise > 70)
            tortoise = 70;
    }// end tortoise
    public void MoveHare()
    {
        // randomize move
        int percent = randomGenerator.Next(1, 10);
        // determine moves by graph
        //big hop
        if (percent == 1 || percent == 2)
            hare += 9;
        //big slip
        else if (percent == 6)
            hare -= 12;
        // small hop
        else if (percent == 3 || percent == 5)
            ++hare;
        // )small slip
        else if (percent == 7 || percent == 8)
            hare -= 2;
        else if (percent == 9 || percent == 10)
            hare += 0;
        //ensure hare doesn't go past start
        if (hare < 1)
            hare = 1;
        // ensure hare doesnt go past end
        else if (hare > 70)
            hare = 70;
    } // end movehare
    public void DisplayCurrentLocation()
    {
        //this is the location of each on the array
        for (int count = 1; count <= 70; count++)
            // same spot
            if (count ==tortoise && count ==hare)
            { 
                System.out.println("OUCH");
            }
            else if (count == hare)
            { 
                System.out.println("H");
            }
            else if (count == tortoise)
            {
                System.out.println("T");
            }
           else
               System.out.println();

    }
public class RaceTest
{
    public static void main ( String[] args)
    {
        Race Application = new Race();
        string request;
        do
     {
        Application.StartRace();
        System.out.println ("");
        System.out.println("Do you want to Play again y/n");
        request = Console.ReadKey();
        if (request == "Y" || request == "y")
        {
            again = true;
        }
        else
        {
            again = false;
        }
     }
    while (again == true);
        System.out.println("Thank you for Playing");
   }
 }
}
```

ERROR MESSAGE:  method next in class java.util.random cannot be applied to given types; required: int, found: int,int; reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Well, yes, you can only call methods that exist.  There is a `next(int)` method on `Random`, and there is no `next(int, int)` method.  You can read [the API doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) to see what methods there are.

Comment: What exactly were you expecting the result of `next(1,10)` to be?

Comment: @JimGarrison   I was expecting the result of next(1, 10) to be a random number (n) between the values of 1 and 10

Comment: @azurefrog Thank you for sharing the doc, should I go into the Java.util.random and change it to allow for int,int?

Comment: You can't change java.util.Random, it's a core part of the language.  What you should do is read about the methods that exist on it, and figure out how to call then to get what you want (hint, take a look at `nextInt()`).

Answer (score 1):

A couple of problems.

First, the method `next(int)` is protected, meaning it is not intended to be invoked by clients (users of the `Random` class).  So you should be using the method `nextInt()`.

Second, to generate a random integer in an arbitrary range, the method `nextInt(int bound)` is the closest thing to this, and it returns an integer between 0 and `bound-1` (inclusive<sup>1</sup>), so to have the same effect use

```
int n = randomGenerator.nextInt(10) + 1;
```

This will generate a random number between 0 and 9 and then add 1 to make the range 1..10.

---

<sup>1</sup> Formally, it returns an integer in the range `[0..bound)`

Comment: Thank you for the help with my program.  I employed the answer that you listed above but now I am getting a new error message saying that next(int) has protected access in Java.util.Random  Do you know what this means? Do you have any suggestions on how to fix this.  Thanks!

Comment: I updated my answer.  I meant to say use `nextInt(10)+1`.  Sorry about that.